# Formatting a date String

Tags: java, android, date

I have a string like this:

`"2013-06-25 10:00:09"`

I want to format it like this:

`"25/06/2013 10:00"`.

I'm trying this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(""dd/MM/yyyy kk:mm"")
    Date d;

    try {
        d = sdf.parse(data_publicao_db[totalCount_ + i]);
        String s2 = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd")).format(d);
        Log.d("Data test", "" + s2);
    }
    catch (ParseException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

But it keeps giving a

```
ParseException: Unparseable date
```

Is there a better and right way to this?

Comment: Is this a copy-paste of the code? What's with the double quotes in the first line?

Comment: Yes, it is a copy and paste from my code. Dunno why the double quotes are there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sdf should be

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

the other SimpleDateFormat you need to reformat your date:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's go!

```
//your date String and SDF in your String format
String originalDateString = "2013-06-25 10:00:09";
SimpleDateFormat originalSdf= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

//get the Date from the String
Date date = originalSdf.parse(originalDateString);

//Wanted output format
SimpleDateFormat wantedSdf= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

//print it
System.out.println(wantedSdf.format(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `data_publicao_db[totalCount_ + i]` is looking like `2013-06-25 10:00:09`, you have to parse it with a format of **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss** .

To convert the result to the format `25/06/2013 10:00`, you have to format it with a SimpleDateFormat using the format **dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm**.